# Faster drawing of map tiles in overlays

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to speed up the drawing of map tiles in my app, since the Time Profiler says that's where the app is running at its slowest. The project files are [here](https://github.com/guthook/TileMapViewer/blob/master/TileMapView/TileOverlayView.m), and the part that the Time Profiler says is slowest is this part of the drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext method for the tile overlay--

```
for (ImageTile *tile in tilesInRect) {
    CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:tile.frame];

    NSString *path = tile.imagePath;
    if (path) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

        float scale = (overZoom/zoomScale);

        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that using any UIImages and scaling them is what is slowing things down the most. Is there any way to speed this up, or to move the drawing to the background thread? (although doesn't drawMapRect happens in the background thread anyway, since it doesn't stop the map scrolling every time the app loads a tile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `drawMapRect` is already run on multiple threads and calling any drawing code directly from a background thread is bad practice and won't increase speed or responsiveness. The bottleneck in your code is most likely the drawing function `CGContextDrawImage` which there may not be much you can do about if you are already sure you are only drawing tiles that intersect the mapRect passed into `drawMapRect:`. However you are calling `UIImage`'s method `imageWithContentsOfFile` repeatedly from multiple threads and I don't believe this caches the image data like the `imageNamed:` method does. You may see a speed increase from fixing this issue. However in my experience you shouldn't be alarmed if the profiler is telling you that it is spending the majority of its time in the `drawMapRect:` method. Since it's called off the main thread and the map is still responsive to user interaction, optimizing it often doesn't hugely improve the user's experience.

Comment: Thanks TheStreaker. This answers the question as best I can understand. I will try the "imageNamed:" method, but it sounds like, in the end, I just need to optimize some other areas of the code to make up for whatever time is spent drawing map tiles. So far, I've cut down some of the time taken by other methods, and it seems to help when testing the app on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be faster, but you might try parallelizing operations if you are dealing with multiple tiles. If you need to offset and/or crop a number of tiles in `tilesInRect`, you could use Grand Central Dispatch or `NSOperationQueue` to do more than one of these at the same time, then have a final assembly step.